# How to change a global variable whose name depends on the context? In python

Tags: python, class, global

I'm coming across a difficulty that I encounter in all my programs.
The thing is, I can not succeed in changing a global variable in a function or in a class if I do not have the name of the variable explicitly writeable.

This is the last example of something that I can not get working:

For the context, the class `inputBox` allows the user to enter text in a box displayed in the window, which is stored in the attribute `self.text`. The class `game` groups many parameters of a question-and-answer-type game, for example the time given per question (`qtime`), the number of questions(`nq`)... I grouped all the boxes of all the games in a list of dictionaries based on the following proto-structure: `gameDictList = [{game1qtime : 20, game1nq : 10}, {game2qtime : 15, game2nq : 5}], etc`

What I want to do is to change the `game` parameters according to what the user enters in `inputBoxes`, but if I write:

```
for box in gameDict :
    gameDict[box] = int(box.text)
    print(gameDict[box]) # print the modified value
    print(CM1game.qtime) # print the (unfortunately) unchanged value
```

`gameDict` being `gameDictList[i]`, `i` being the game at stake.

I understand the problem as follows: I cannot change the class variable that `gameDict[box]` redirects to, but I also cannot declare it global because its name depends on the situation. I also cannot write `global game1.qtime` in my program, unless I want an error raising in my program.
My question is, is there a way of getting this up and working? Should I redesign the structure of my program and build these methods with predictable lists of parameters (the first item always referencing the `qtime`, the second `nq`...), this complexifying my code and restricting me to the parameters I can use; is there something that I am doing wrong?

I thank you for reading this, hoping to find an answer.

William

Answer (score 0):

I don't think changing from dict to list helps at all.

In your code example, why would you expect `CM1game.qtime` to change?

So to untangle, it seems like you have a class `Game` that has parameters like `qtime`.

And then you want to display input boxes, where each input box is associated with a given game instance and a given parameter.

So then somewhere in your code will you need to establish that connection, and it's better to make that connection explicit, e.g. via a dictionary that maps input boxes to the related game object they're supposed to modify. That's much better than relying on the format of a global variable name.

Comment: So here's more detail for you @Lagerbaer to understand my issue: ```game``` has attributes like ```qtime```. The user can edit ```inputBoxes``` willing to change these attributes. An ```inputBox``` is not related to a game, but I created a dictionary built on this model: ```gameDict = {inputBox1 : game1.qtime, inputBox2: game1.nq}```, as I want these parameters to change along with the user input (stored as```inputBox1.text```). However, I lack the syntax to change ```game1.qtime```: I wrote ```gameDict[box] = inputBox1.text``` in a ```game``` method but ```game1.qtime``` stays the same.